# How should I import AccessibilityInfo in a react native expo managed app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on my first React Native project. It's an expo managed app with SDK 33.

I want to use the AccessibilityInfo API as described in the expo documentation here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v33.0.0/react-native/accessibilityinfo/

The example on that page is straight forward but there's one thing missing: where do I import AccessibilityInfo from? My IDE autocomplete suggests to `import {AccessibilityInfo} from "react-native-web";` but that seems wrong because I understand that react-native-web is to help bring react-native features into a web app.

So instead I do `import {AccessibilityInfo} from "react-native";`

But when I try to do the following in my component:

```
componentDidMount () {
    AccessibilityInfo.isScreenReaderEnabled().then( (screenReaderEnabled) => {
        console.log(screenReaderEnabled);
    });
}
```

I get a "TypeError: _reactNative.AccessibilityInfo.isScreenReaderEnabled is not a function".

According to my IDE's autocomplete, the AccessibilityInfo module only has the following methods: `addEventListener`, `announceForAccessibilty`, `fetch`, `removeEventListener`, `setAccessibilityFocus`. But according to the expo documentation linked above, I should have other methods such as `isScreenReaderEnabled`.

My only guess is that I'm not importing the correct module. But I didn't find anything interesting while googling around. So can anyone point me in the right direction to help me solve that problem?

Comment: Could you try this? `import AccessibilityInfo from "AccessibilityInfo"`

Comment: @Train: I know it's in the source code, as it is in the documentation. That's why I don't understand why I don't have access to it...

Comment: @hongdevelop: importing from AccessibilityInfo is returning an undefined error...

Comment: I gave the wrong link look at the `ScreenReaderStatusExample` component and how they use it https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3b6f6ca4d5fcee6f1bc6d6242e3e2ef136e4d546/RNTester/js/examples/Accessibility/AccessibilityExample.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3b6f6ca4d5fcee6f1bc6d6242e3e2ef136e4d546/RNTester/js/examples/Accessibility/AccessibilityExample.js) they have this example

```
import {AccessibilityInfo} from "react-native";
...
    class ScreenReaderStatusExample extends React.Component<{}> {
      state = {
        screenReaderEnabled: false,
      };

      componentDidMount() {
        AccessibilityInfo.addEventListener(
          'change',
          this._handleScreenReaderToggled,
        );
        AccessibilityInfo.fetch().done(isEnabled => {
          this.setState({
            screenReaderEnabled: isEnabled,
          });
        });
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        AccessibilityInfo.removeEventListener(
          'change',
          this._handleScreenReaderToggled,
        );
      }

      _handleScreenReaderToggled = isEnabled => {
        this.setState({
          screenReaderEnabled: isEnabled,
        });
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>
              The screen reader is{' '}
              {this.state.screenReaderEnabled ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'}.
            </Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

In there example all their doing is calling Fetch and not working with the variable directly

```
  componentDidMount() {
...
    AccessibilityInfo.fetch().done(isEnabled => {
      this.setState({
        screenReaderEnabled: isEnabled,
      });
    });
  }
```

the fetch returns the `IsEnabled` status

so in your `ComponentDidMount`
change it from

```
AccessibilityInfo.isScreenReaderEnabled().then( (screenReaderEnabled) => {
    console.log(screenReaderEnabled);
});
```

to

```
AccessibilityInfo.fetch().done(isEnabled => {
  this.setState({
    screenReaderEnabled: isEnabled,
  });
});
```

and hold the isEnabled response in state.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that .fetch() is doing what isScreenReaderEnabled() is supposed to do in the documentation. I guess that the documentation is not up to date and that's the source of this problem... Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!